# Spring KafkaTemplate cannot find bootstrap server on OpenShift

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, openshift

I am working on moving a Spring sink microservice from my local machine to the OpenShift platform. Inside of my microservice I create a KafkaTemplate like this:

@Autowired
KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

Using this method to send Kafka message works perfectly fine on my local machine, when I move to OpenShift however I get this error:

Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.

I find this to be a little confusing because I when my microservice goes up I can see the address of the Kafka servers in the logs and because other Kafka functions seem to work fine (I am able to read out from the Kafka topic that my processor microservice is writing into). I have been able to work around this issue is to manually create a ProducerFactory and set ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG equal to the bootstrap server address I found in the logs.

So I guess I have a couple of questions: One, is KafkaTemplate only wired to run locally or is there a way to wire it to use the bootstrap server assigned after the service goes up? If not is there a way to get the bootstrap server that I am seeing in the logs? Obviously my service has access to it at one point so is there some way I could dynamically set the BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG equal to the value that is being printed in the logs?

Or is there a better way to write out to a Kafka topic from a Spring sink microservice?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: OpenShift should expose your Kafka service over a DNS name. You would need to add this, at the very least, as an environment variable to your container to load into the `application.properties` under `spring.kafka.bootstrap.servers` (or you can define a ProducerFactory in the code)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I can definitely add an environment variable to designate the bootstrap servers but they wouldn't be able to be dynamically defined after the service goes up, correct? And if I were to create my own producer is there a way to get the bootstrap server already in use?

Comment: The Kafka service shouldn't be changing after you deploy your app, so not sure I understand the need for anything "dynamic". If you just need access to the string, you again access the Spring configuration object, or just the env-var you've set. Here's example code for Strimzi (a Kafka Kubernetes operator) https://github.com/strimzi/client-examples/blob/master/java/kafka/producer/src/main/java/KafkaProducerConfig.java#L60